# Dealing with large numbers for space physics

Tags: python, windows, floating-point, python-3.7, game-physics

I am trying to make a pygame app that uses realistic physics to simulate a solar system. When I use large numbers such as the mass of the sun or Earths distance from the sun I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Solar System Simulator/solsyssim.py", line 103, in <module>
    run_again = main()
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Solar System Simulator/solsyssim.py", line 94, in main
    body.draw(screen, zoom, translation)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Solar System Simulator\body.py", line 50, in draw
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (int(self.x * zoom + translation[0]), int(self.y * zoom + translation[1])), round(self.radius * zoom))
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I have tried using smaller numbers that are ratios of the masses (Sun is 150kg and the Earth is sun.mass * 0.00000300251), but this becomes really complicated the more planets I add, and I cannot do this for the distance from the sun. I have tried putting the numbers in Scientific notation, but that also causes issues.

This is my body.py file (I removed all the scaling math and anything that didn't use the large numbers)

```py
#body.py
import math
import pygame


G = 6.673 * (10 ** -11)

class Body:
    def __init__(self, x, y, bodies, mass=1000, radius=25, color=(255, 255, 0), xv=0, yv=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.xv = xv
        self.yv = yv
        self.mass = mass
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.bodies = bodies

    def tick(self):
        xf, yf = 0, 0
        for body in self.bodies:
            if body != self:
                v = self.force(body)
                xf += (math.cos(v.angle) * v.force) * body_data.force_scale
                yf += (math.sin(v.angle) * v.force) * body_data.force_scale

        self.xv += xf / self.mass
        self.yv += yf / self.mass

        self.x += self.xv
        self.y += self.yv

    def draw(self, screen, zoom, translation):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (math.floor(self.x), math.floor(self.y)), math.floor(self.radius))

    def dist(self, b):
        return math.sqrt(((b.x - self.x)**2) + ((b.y - self.y) ** 2))

    def angle(self, b):
        return math.atan2(b.y - self.y, b.x - self.x)

    def force(self, b):
        return Vector2D((G * b.mass * self.mass) / self.dist(b), self.angle(b))


class Vector2D:
    def __init__(self, force, angle):
        self.force = force
        self.angle = angle
```

These are snippets of my main.py file which is what creates Body objects with the large numbers.

```py
sun_mass = 1.9891e30
earth_mass = 5.972e24
earth_dist = 149.6 * 10**6
```

and

```py
sun = Body(winsize[0] // 2, winsize[1] // 2, bodies, sun_mass, 25)
earth = Body(sun.x - earth_distance, size[1] // 2, bodies, earth_mass, 10, (0, 0, 255), 0, initial_velocity)
```

Here's my scaling/translation calculation that is run every tick, and is passed into the body.draw function:

```py
def get_zoom(bodies):
    d = 0
    for body in bodies:
        d = max(body.y, body.x, d)

    print("D:", d, "/", max(size))
    return max(size) / (d * 2)


def get_translation(zoom):
    return size[0] // 2 - (size[0] // 2 * zoom), size[0] // 2 - (size[1] // 2 * zoom)
```

I don't know how to draw the circles for the planets if the numbers are too large to be converted to ints and pygame.draw.circle needs the numbers to be ints.

EDIT: Thank you everybody for the suggestions and trying to help me! I ended up doing what `pault` suggested, but I scaled down all the distances when drawing, without scaling down the masses so the physics are still realistic. Again thank you guys for all the help and troubleshooting help; it really helped me learn more about Python!

Comment: one option is to scale everything down to smaller numbers...so instead of km use 1000's of km, etc

Comment: I tried to do that too, but it causes a lot of issues with the force calculations. I have tried making it convert back to kms and kgs when it calculates force, but it still has problems.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7

Comment: What system are you on?  Is python 64 bit?

Comment: I am on windows, and my python is 32-bit. I do not have the option of downloading 64-bit (it's a school PC)

Comment: What's Vector2D? Can you show a full traceback? Which line raised the error?

Comment: I shortened the program in order to follow question guidelines, but the problem is caused by the pygame.draw.circle function. Vector2D is just a class that contains the Force applied to a body at an angle.

Comment: @BenMorrison your best bet would be to move over to a 64bit system. What does `python -c "import sys; print(sys.maxsize)` give you?

Comment: It prints 2147483647 which I believe is the 32-bit maximum. I looked at other questions on here about this stuff, but I couldn't find an answer that would work with my program. I am using quite large numbers.

Comment: too large even for 64 bit? otherwise your only option will be to do like `pault` said, because the pygame library is using c longs, apparently

Comment: I believe the mass of the sun in kg is much too large for python 32-bit (I cannot change to 64-bit), so I am trying to think of a way to use the real x and y coords, but scale down the number (LIKE CRAZY) in order to draw it.

Comment: There's a third-party module named [`mpmath`](https://pypi.org/project/mpmath/) that can handle arbitrary-precision floating-point arithmetic. I don't know for sure, but think it's likely to have the ability to convert one of its arbitrary-precision floating-point numbers into a built-in Python integer (which are already arbitrary-precision). Here's the [documentation](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/) for the library.

Comment: I think a traceback (or at least telling us on which *line* this error happened) will help a lot. The way I see it, you are using a lot of large *floats*, and that should be OK. The problem is where the large *int* appeared.

Comment: I added the traceback, but it is not correct because I shortened the program in order to follow question guidelines. The error occured in the draw function as I said in a previous comment.

Comment: An [mcve] wouldn't need to use `pygame` — just something showing (or perhaps calculating) a large floating-point number that can't be converted into an Python `int` would suffice.

Comment: @martineau Not needing pygame didn't even occur to me, I need to think how to simplify my questions more in the future.

Comment: @martineau Yeah I tried to simplify my code, but I was really tired and I just couldn't think well. I'll try to do better next time.